# How to Delete lines that contain more than three dots in a email before @ character using SED?

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

```
sed '/\(.*\..*\)\{4,\}/d'
```

The above command mentioned recognizes every DOT in the line...

It is recognizing DOTS after @ sign too. 
For example, even this is shown in the result: ryisan@Sariyer.Cc.itu.Edu.tr

Can you help me modify the above command in such a way that only the LEFT side of @ it counts the Multiple DOTS more than 3 and ignores the DOTS after the character @ to right side of the email?

Eg:

```
fgtc21_pk@yahoo.com
bhchemitex@chemitex.com
hjcindysun48@hotmail.com
hhconsult_sa.jan.2020@yahoo.com
s.ing.song.lan.g.ju.n.55.l@gmail.com
VB.t.o.t.all.y.f.it.s.19.99@yahoo.com
a.lice.i.n.wonde.r.lnd.2.1.f@dkg.com
ryisan@Sariyer.Cc.itu.Edu.tr
```

I want the following lines with multiple Dots (3 or more dots) at the LEFT SIDE of @ Character to be only recognizers and deleted from the file.

```
s.ing.song.lan.g.ju.n.55.l@gmail.com
VB.t.o.t.all.y.f.it.s.19.99@yahoo.com
a.lice.i.n.wonde.r.lnd.2.1.f@dkg.com
```

Any experts, plz suggest me how to modify the above SED command.... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert but, to delete only the 4 dots (or more) patterns at the left side of `@` you can simply add `@.*` at the end of your expression:

```
sed '/\(.*\..*\)\{4,\}@.*/d'
```

It means to delete the 4 dots (or more) patterns at the left side of the `@` regardless what characters are at the right side.